# Что следует добавить в .gitignore в проекте Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel5

Нужно выкатить приложение на сервер рабочий. Что точно не нужно пушить в репозиторий? Меня вот волнует вопрос с миграциями, как с ними быть?

Comment: Короткий ответ на вопрос в заголовке - https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Laravel.gitignore

Comment: @insolor , А вот еще вопрос, почему мы .env файл в игнор добавляем? Как он потом сгенерится на стороне сервера? Или потом вручную его ставить?

Comment: .env для каждого сервера скорее всего свой будет, поэтому он не должен быть в гите, а настраиваться для конкретного сервера. Или допустим вы тестируете, в .env прописываете свои локальные настройки, у кого-то другого настройки будут другие, он пушит в гит, и его настройки затирают ваши.

Comment: @insolor, Спасибо!

Comment: пушится в гит .env.example он как раз нужен для дефолтных настроек запуска проекта. Далее данные из него разработчик берет в свой .env когда первый раз проект запускает. Далее всякие новые записи дублируются в .env.example чтобы разработчик потом если что там смотрел. Боевые ключи туда нельзя указывать, только для развертывания на тестовой машине или локальной